# How can I perform a "like" or "contains" search on a string?

Tags: javascript

Can I compare an especific value of an array in a if() conditional ?

Ex.:

```
// teacher object
function Prof(id,tab,nome,ocupacao,email,tel,foto)
{
   this.id  = id;
   this.tab = tab;
   this.nome    = nome;
   this.ocupacao= ocupacao;
   this.email   = email;
   this.tel = tel;
   this.foto    = foto;
}

//teachers array
var arr = new Array();
arr[0]  = new Prof('pf1','dir','Mario','Diretor','mail@mail.com','tel','foto');
arr[1]  = new Prof('pf2','dir','Joao','t1 t3 t7','...','...','...');
...

// So now i will get the array value of "ocupacao" and see if this value has
// an specific value that i´ve defined in the conditional:
...
if(arr[i].ocupacao (has value) t7)
{
    //do something
}
```

NOTE; There is something that i can use like in PHP or ASP: "LIKE" or "%value%"?

Comment: I changed the title. This question has nothing to do with arrays. `arr[i]` results in a *value* when the expression is applied. Let's say `x1 = arr[i]` and `x2 = x1.ocupacao` then observe `x2` *is the same value* as `arr[i].ocupacao`. The thing being looked for is the operation to perform on said *resulting value* to determine "contains". Note that `ocupacao` contains a string, not an array.

Comment: Unless perhaps the goal is to search all the `arr[0] ... arr[n]` "at once"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(arr[i].ocupacao.indexOf('t7') >= 0)
{
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are referring to the *ocupacao array* but you inherently mean the ocupacao string that is made by many words separated by spaces..

Then you could do it in three ways:

- either with regular expression matching withing the string
- either by splitting the string into a real array and then check if it contains what you need (actually jQuery has a shorthand which is `$.inArray(...)` otherwise you will have to loop through the array and search for it
- (forgot to add) `Array.indexOf` which will return -1 if item is not found